# xcode: TextField.text return nil no matter what is the input: [New Referencing Outlet]?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a tab-bar application. 
In one of the view(.xib), there is a text field and a button. The button supposed to save the text inputted in textField.

However, no matter what i typed, it always read (nil) in textField.text in debug.

When i right click the textField in .xib, i cannot drag the [New Referencing Outlet] to [File's Owner]. i can only drag the [delegate] to [File's Owner]. Does anyone have idea on why i can't do so?

Below the the .h file:

---

```
@interface AddDebtorViewController : UIViewController
{
    UITextField *tDebtorName;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tDebtorName;

-(IBAction)returnButPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)addDebtorButPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

---

Below is the .m file:

---

```
#import "AddDebtorViewController.h"
@implementation AddDebtorViewController
@synthesize tDebtorName;

- (IBAction)addDebtorButPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *debtorName = [[NSString alloc] init]; 
    debtorName = tDebtorName.text;
    NSLog(debtorName);
}
...
@end
```

---

Comment: You have to connect your UITextfield component with tDebtorName Outlet. So that you can get an input from that textfield

Answer (score 1):

You must select File's Owner, press right button mouse, find your outlet and link it with the ui element.

Comment: When i right-click, then under "New Referencing Outlet" i drag it to the textField, it only have the "delegate" option. So i choose delegate option. And its not working. When i right-click the textField, it shows [delegate] => [File's Owner] under Owner, but not [New Referencing Outlet].

Comment: I've completely rewritten my answer, sorry for inconvenience. May be types of outlet and ui element are differs? In this case you cant link them in IB.

Comment: When i right-click, then under "New Referencing Outlet" i drag it to the textField, it only have the "delegate" option. So i choose delegate option. And its not working. When i right-click the textField, it shows [delegate] => [File's Owner] under Owner, but not under [Referencing Outlet].

Comment: 1. Check if types of outlet and ui object are the same. 2. Check if Files'Owner properly configured ("Class" property in identity inspector, must be equal to "AddDebtorViewController")